# Specify a parameter for using files inside a Jar

Tags: java, properties, jar, embedded-resource

Say `log.properties` is in the `test.jar`.  I would like to specify the file parameter using some file inside the jar, is this doable?

```
-DLog=target/classes/log.properties
```

Comment: *"Specify a parameter for using files inside a Jar"*  Resources in an archive are not files and cannot be used as a `File` object.  They must be accessed by URL.

Answer (score 1):

Though question is not that clear to me, I will try to answer:

If you have are loading your parameter'd file with:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileParameter);
```

then even if your file is inside jar (in classpath) it should work. And you should be able to pass parameter something as `-DLog=log.properties`, so that it will search all the possible paths in classpath.

Comment: Also, this link should help - http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html